# Extracting parts of whitespace seperated string

Tags: git, shell, sed, command-substitution

If have several Git repositories containing a file `mergedriver.info`

This file looks always like this:

```
<project name>
<repository name>
```

A script, triggered by a Git merge driver, is evaluating this file:

```
mergedriverinfo="$(git cat-file -p HEAD:mergedriver.info)"
success=$?
if [[ "$success" == "0" ]]; then
    log "Evaluating mergedriver.info"

    PROJECT_KEY="$(sed -E 's/([^\s]+)\s+([^\s]+)/\1/' <<< $mergedriverinfo)"
    REPO_SLUG="$(sed -E 's/([^\s]+)\s+([^\s]+)/\2/' <<< $mergedriverinfo)"

    log "PROJECT_KEY=$PROJECT_KEY"
    log "REPO_SLUG=$REPO_SLUG"
else
    log "Unable to read mergedriver.info"
    exit 1
fi
```

I don't understand the behaviour of sed in this case.

For this `mergedriver.info`:

```
test
conflict-on-auto-merge
```

The log output looks like this:

```
2017-07-20 11:05:51.747 PROJECT_KEY=test
2017-07-20 11:05:51.748 REPO_SLUG=tesconflict-on-auto-merge
```

At first I tried reading the mergedriver.info with sed -n 1p/2p and head/tail -1, but unfortunately the output of `$(git cat-file -p HEAD:mergedriver.info)` is different for two different platforms on which this script is running:

Platform 1:

```
$ od -c <<< $(git cat-file -p HEAD:mergedriver.info)
0000000   t   e   s   t  \n   c   o   n   f   l   i   c   t   -   o   n
0000020   -   a   u   t   o   -   m   e   r   g   e  \n
0000034
```

Platform 2:

```
±  od -c <<< $(git cat-file -p HEAD:mergedriver.info)
0000000   t   e   s   t       c   o   n   f   l   i   c   t   -   o   n
0000020   -   a   u   t   o   -   m   e   r   g   e  \n
0000034
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Put quotes around `$mergedriverinfo` inside your command substitutions.

Comment: Well, that changed something, but:
2017-07-20 11:44:58.272 PROJECT_KEY=test
conflict-on-auto-merge
2017-07-20 11:44:58.273 REPO_SLUG=test
conflict-on-auto-merge

Comment: `od -c <<< $(git cat-file -p HEAD:mergedriver.info)` should also have quotes around `$()`

Comment: Quoting the command substituion is preserving the \n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `<<<`, then I guess you're using bash, so you can use `mapfile` to split your variable into an array, one element per line:

```
$ echo "$mergedriverinfo"
test
conflict-on-auto-merge
$ mapfile -t lines <<<"$mergedriverinfo"
$ echo "${lines[0]}"
test
$ echo "${lines[1]}"
conflict-on-auto-merge
```

So your project key is element 0 and the repo slug is element 1.

Comment: I tested this soltution and it works fine, but I already solved the problem using another fine solution I got from Rakesh Sharma on unix.stackexchange.com:

PROJECT_KEY=$(sed -nEe '$!N;s/(\S+)\s+(\S+)/\1/p' <<<"$mergedriverinfo")
  REPO_SLUG=$(sed -nEe '$!N;s/(\S+)\s+(\S+)/\2/p' <<<"$mergedriverinfo")

Comment: I'm not sure why you would want to use two calls to `sed` rather than one call to a built-in command. Also note that you shouldn't cross-post the same question on multiple sites.